# Add an Additional Shipping Address to the Sales Order

Tags: c#, acumatica

Version 22.115

I'm trying to add another shipping address to the sales order screen - SO301000.  I want it to work exactly like the "Ship-To Address" that is out of the box.  I added a custom integer field to the SOOrder record in order to relate to an SOShippingAddress record just like the SOOrder.ShipAddressID.  Also, I added a view to my SOOrderEntry graph extension for the new shipping address record.

The problem that I'm having is that whenever I update my custom shipping address on the screen, it updates to out of the box "Ship-To Address" when I click Save on the sales order.    For instance, if I click the "Override Address" checkbox on my custom address, and click Save on the sales order, it shows the Override Address checkbox as checked on the out of the box shipping address.

I'm thinking that there is some code somewhere that is looking at the DAC record type and updating the SOOrder.ShipAddressID field whenever that type of record is persisted?  Not sure...

I tried making a DAC that inherits from SOAddress like the below but, still have an issue.

```
[PXCacheName("MySOAddress")]
public class MySOAddress : SOAddress { }
```

Here's the view on my SOOrderEntry graph extension:

```
 [PXViewName(MyMessages.CustomShipToAddress)]
 public PXSelect<MySOAddress, Where<MySOAddress.addressID, 
 Equal<Current<SOOrderExt.usrMyAddressID>>>> CustomShipTo_Address;
```

Here's the integer field that I setup on the SOOrder DAC extension:

```
    #region UsrMyAddressID
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault(typeof(SOOrder.shipAddressID), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Address ID")]
    [PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(MySOAddress.addressID))]
    public int? UsrMyAddressID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrMyAddressID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrMyAddressID> { }
```

Any insights or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused. If I'm reading your DAC extension field correctly, it's defaulting to the original ship-to address, but there's no selector or anything on it. How are you even able to pick a different address?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer (yet), but elaborating on my comment, I would expect to see something like this for your extension field:

```
    [PXDBInt()]
    [SOShippingAddress(typeof(
                Select2<Address,
                    InnerJoin<CRLocation,
              On<CRLocation.bAccountID, Equal<Address.bAccountID>,
             And<Address.addressID, Equal<CRLocation.defAddressID>,
                 And<CRLocation.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                        And<CRLocation.locationID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerLocationID>>>>>>,
                    LeftJoin<SOShippingAddress,
                        On<SOShippingAddress.customerID, Equal<Address.bAccountID>,
                        And<SOShippingAddress.customerAddressID, Equal<Address.addressID>,
                        And<SOShippingAddress.revisionID, Equal<Address.revisionID>,
                        And<SOShippingAddress.isDefaultAddress, Equal<True>>>>>>>,
                    Where<True, Equal<True>>>))]
    [PXDefault(typeof(SOOrder.shipAddressID), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Address ID")]
    public virtual int? UsrMyAddressID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrMyAddressID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrMyAddressID> { }
```